# Image not added to the contact

Tags: android-contacts

Below is the code I used to add contact when we click on the notification.
Everything else gets added to the contact, except the image, what am I missing?

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bmp.getWidth() * bmp.getHeight());
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        final int notificationId = new Random().nextInt();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        notificationIntent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, context.getString(R.string.contact_name));
        notificationIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, context.getString(R.string.notification_number));
        notificationIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, context.getString(R.string.notification));
        notificationIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE, context.getString(R.string.monitor_number));
        notificationIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE_TYPE, context.getString(R.string.monitor_name));
        notificationIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, byteArray);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.contact_title))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.contact_message))
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(context.getString(R.string.contact_message)))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


 NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Comment: Any suggestions will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I removed the line

```
 notificationIntent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

and then added

```
 ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
        row.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        row.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, byteArray);
        data.add(row);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
notificationIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);
```